# Using CombinedGeometry to join two polygons in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I'm using `CombinedGeometry` to merged several rectangles together. Here is the code I have used.

It is a bit lengthy but the gist of it is that two rectangles are combined into a single geometry here and the final geometry is passed to `Path.Data`.

Now when I merge these as you see in the picture below, when the two rectangles join each other, the joint is rather ugly. I was wondering if there is way to make it look a bit nicer as shown with the red marker?

[image]

```
<Canvas Width="1000" Height="1000">
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Transparent" x:Name="MyPath" >
    </Path>
</Canvas>

public class MyRect
{
    public double X1 { get; set; }
    public double Y1 { get; set; }
    public double X2 { get; set; }
    public double Y2 { get; set; }
    public double X3 { get; set; }
    public double Y3 { get; set; }
    public double X4 { get; set; }
    public double Y4 { get; set; }
}

var cg = new CombinedGeometry { GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Union };

var rect1 = new MyRect { X1 = 500, Y1 = 120, X2 = 1000, Y2 = 120, X3 = 1000, Y3 = 80, X4 = 500, Y4 = 80 };
var rect2 = new MyRect { X1 = 480, Y1 = 100, X2 = 480, Y2 = 200, X3 = 520, Y3 = 200, X4 = 520, Y4 = 100 };

var list = new List<MyRect>
{
    rect1, rect2
};

var geometry = new PathGeometry();

var myRec = list[0];
var la = new LineSegment { Point = new Point(myRec.X2, myRec.Y2) };
var lb = new LineSegment { Point = new Point(myRec.X3, myRec.Y3) };
var lc = new LineSegment { Point = new Point(myRec.X4, myRec.Y4) };
var pathFigure = new PathFigure
{
    StartPoint = new Point(myRec.X1, myRec.Y1),
    Segments = { la, lb, lc }
};

var path = new PathGeometry { Figures = { pathFigure } };
cg.Geometry1 = path;
for (var i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    myRec = list[i];

    la = new LineSegment { Point = new Point(myRec.X2, myRec.Y2) };
    lb = new LineSegment { Point = new Point(myRec.X3, myRec.Y3) };
    lc = new LineSegment { Point = new Point(myRec.X4, myRec.Y4) };
    pathFigure = new PathFigure
    {
        StartPoint = new Point(myRec.X1, myRec.Y1),
        Segments = { la, lb, lc }
    };

    path = new PathGeometry { Figures = { pathFigure } };
    cg.Geometry2 = path;

    geometry = cg.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
    cg.Geometry1 = geometry;
}
MyPath.Data = geometry;
```

Comment: Do all rectangles in the same `Path` have the same thickness (40 in your example)? If yes, then I would recommend not to use rectangles at all, and instead use a `Pen` with thickness 40. Then, `Path.StrokeMiterLimit` ensures that the lines have a beveled joined.

Comment: @fmunkert No they may have different widths, consider them as beams in a structural plan, and they need to be unfilled, only outer lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk the combined path and merge edge-pairs where both edges are shorter than some X?

X could be set to something just below the min length of any rectangle's side, so you won't alter original features, just clean up small artifacts what you have in your picture.

Depends on your source data and if you have any non-trivial cases.

Comment: Thanks Macke, I get what you mean. This is an old question. I needed an algorithm to draw the outlines of single lines, like a structural plan. Back then, I found out that using `CombinedGeometry` is not efficient for larger projects, and implemented my own algorithm and handled the corners like you are suggesting.

Comment: Nice. What was inefficient about CombinedGeometry? I'm thinking about using it myself to combine polygons created from WMF/AutoCAD files, but I don't need any simplificaiton. Maybe StreamGeometry is better anyway?

Comment: I don't know what algorithms are implemented behind the scenes for `CombinedGeometry` but it seems it is just for simple applications. It doesn't scale well when you have hundreds of lines which is pretty reasonable in a CAD application. I, actually, wanted this to write a CAD/Detailing software and finally came up with my own custom solution: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxYqjWcL5iwlWEZGdnhadlVJLWc/view?usp=sharing